Auto delete Rows with dates older than today
Made a Form that sends responses to a Google Sheet including delivery date.  Have gotten it to Auto Sort when the form is submitted so that the earliest dates/times are at the top.  Currently would need to go through and delete the deliveries that have already passed every morning, but was hoping someone could help me with a script that would do that automatically every morning.  Thanks.
enter image description here
Sorry, I am very new at writing scripts and don't even know where to start with this.

Do you want to delete every row with a col Detail "Completed"?
If so, here is a small function you can put in your spreadsheet, adding a time based trigger:
function deleteCompletedRow() {
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
const sheetData = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
const sheetDataHeaders = sheetData[0];
for (let i = sheetData.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    if (sheetData[i][sheetDataHeaders.indexOf("Detail")] == "Completed") {
        sheet.deleteRow(i + 1);
    }
}

}
Hope that helps!

Thank you so much.  I appreciate it.
If its possible to get something that will delete based on date (today is 4/12 so this morning it deletes all the rows with 4/11 in the delivery date column) that would be best as sometimes we detail the car the night before and I don't want it to delete it too early.  If this is the only option then that's fine.  Does this already have a time based trigger on it?  If so, what is it, and how would I edit it?  Or do I need to set up a trigger?

Of course, here is a new snippet:
function deleteCompletedRow() {     const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();     const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");     const sheetData = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();     const sheetDataHeaders = sheetData[0];     const yesterday = new Date();     yesterday.setDate(yesterday.getDate() - 1);     for (let i = sheetData.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {         if (sheetData[i][sheetDataHeaders.indexOf("Date")] < yesterday) {             sheet.deleteRow(i + 1);         }     } }

To set up your trigger, simply open Apps Script, on the left panel you will see a chrono icon for triggers. You can click on it and then "Add trigger", you can choose time based and the function you want to run!

Do i need to edit anything to get it to work with my sheet?  I tried running it and it didnt do anything.  Im trying to delete the row if the date in column "F" is yesterday.  Thank you.

function deleteCompletedRow() {     const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();     const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");     const sheetData = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();     const sheetDataHeaders = sheetData[0];     const yesterday = new Date();     yesterday.setDate(yesterday.getDate() - 1);     for (let i = sheetData.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {         if (sheetData[i][sheetDataHeaders.indexOf("Delivery Date")] < yesterday) {             sheet.deleteRow(i + 1);         }     } }

To check the col F, just change the value to check of the headers for "Delivery date" as shown in my previous comment. I always write my code like that, so if the column is moved, the script continues to work :)
